# Equation for Fourier transforms

Tags: fourier-transform, integration, complex-numbers

I am aware that the formula to transform a time-dependent function $f(t)$ into the frequency domain is$$\hat f(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i\omega t}f(t)dt.$$I understand the role that $e^{i\omega t}$ plays in this function, as it "filters out" all the components that alternate at an angular frequency other than $\omega$ (the value of its correlation function with any of these functions is $0$). However, it seems to me that any function with period $\omega$ would work equally well in the place of $e^{i\omega t}$. So what is the point of the imaginary component here? Why is the Fourier transform not just $\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\cos(\omega t) \, f(t) \, dt$?

Comment: We can (and some do) define Fourier transforms using sine and cosine: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine_transforms

Comment: Ask yourself what would happen in the case $f(t) = \sin(\omega' t)$, and then ask whether that is a good thing if the transform is supposed to tell you "what is the frequency content of $f(t)$ at various frequencies?"

Comment: $e^{i\omega t} = cos(\omega t) + isin (\omega t)$, so it works out perfectly as is.

Comment: it must be $-i$ instead of $i$

Comment: @Masacroso the $\pm i$ is just a convention. Yes I prefer $-$ (in fact $-2\pi i \omega$), but ultimately it is just a convention, and I've seen different texts use both conventions. So, it's not a must to have the negative sign (what is a must is the inverse transform must have the opposite sign, and with the correct $2\pi$ normalization of course).

Comment: A transform defined as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \cos(\omega t)\,dt$ would yield only even functions of $\omega$.  The transform $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{i\omega t}\,dt$ admits both even, odd, or neither even not odd results.